# asp.net mvc 4 dropdownlist does not return a value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have 2 models - Question and Category -

```
public class Question
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string AnswerA { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string AnswerB { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string AnswerC { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string AnswerD { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Correct { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    [Display(Name = "Category")]
    [Required]
    public int categoryId;

    //Navigation property
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Question> Question { get; set; }
}
```

In my QuestionController, I have added code to be able to access the available categories for a dropdownlist in the view -

```
 private void PopulateCategoryDropDownList(object selectedCategory = null)
    {
        var categoryQuery = from c in db.Categories
                               orderby c.Name
                               select c;
        ViewBag.categoryId = new SelectList(categoryQuery, "CategoryId", "Name", selectedCategory);
    }
```

And I have the following methods for create -

```
// GET: /Question/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        PopulateCategoryDropDownList();
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Question/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Question question)
    {
        try
        {
            var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Questions.Add(question);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        catch (DataException dex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("",dex.Message);
        }
        PopulateCategoryDropDownList(question.Category.CategoryId);
        return View(question);
    }
```

My view for creating a new question is as follows - 
    @model Quiz.Models.Question

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Question</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QuestionText)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QuestionText)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QuestionText)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AnswerA)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AnswerA)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AnswerA)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AnswerB)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AnswerB)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AnswerB)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AnswerC)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AnswerC)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AnswerC)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AnswerD)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AnswerD)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AnswerD)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Correct)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Correct)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Correct)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.categoryId)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.categoryId,(SelectList)ViewBag.categoryId)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.categoryId)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

So, the issue is that although the question can be created, the categoryId from the dropdownlist is always null.

[image]

[image: The first image shows the create page, and the second one is the create method on breakpoint]

I have tried a bunch of things, ranging from attempting to access the dropdownlist directly to creating a different viewmodel. However, none of them work as required. Also, my code follows the tutorials available online. I'm not able to figure out what is different.

Please do help me find the mistake in my code.

Comment: Can you please remove the Question object and use fromcollection, it will give you everything that is coming from post request. There must be some spelling mistake.

Comment: i'm not sure i follow... can you tell me exactly what to do?

Comment: ok, i tried with FormCollection, but that returns just the properties as strings.

Comment: try using @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Category.CategoryId...

Comment: @Madhu formcollection should give string and values too. Can you dump the details what you get.

Comment: check what html is generated by your @Html.DropDownListFor and write here please...

Comment: @kunjee Yes, i was able to get it working using formcollection - q.CategoryId = Int16.Parse(question.GetValue("CategoryId").AttemptedValue); It is a good workaround for create. But, is there a way to find out why built-in mvc is not working. Also, I'm not sure how to make edit work this way.

Comment: @Madhu I suggested not as work around. :). It is to debug only. MVC is able to do nested model binding. So, it is possible. But I always prefer flat model as view model. Or at least I try that. In your case binding is not happening while posting data but data is coming. So, issue is either spelling or some property is missing so null is coming back. I try to reproduce that, when I go home till then if you want you can debug the model binding issue.

Comment: @kunjee - Thank you so much for the help! I was able to get some data using Elliot's technique. There was a catch though- only the question.Category.CategoryId was populated, question.CategoryId and question.Category.Name was null. I was able to get this information. But the ModelState still showed an error for question.Category.Name. Is there a way to reset the ModelState errors? Or should I not bother with, and directly execute the save?

Comment: @Madhu with your current state if you are in hurry just skip modelstate for now. But it is not advisable. And there should be value in question.category.categoryID and question.category.Name if it is not happening something is still wrong.

Comment: @kunjee yes, i need to roll with this now. but, how do i begin to troubleshoot the modelstate? is there a way to trace it?

Comment: @Madhu If I remember correctly you can debug it from global.asax.cs. Just google it how to do custom model binding and you will get all the details needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We might have to narrow things down, I have a feeling something is going wrong with the models being read correctly from ViewBag. Try replacing your `Create` actions for a moment with the following, where your custom ViewBag filling function has been removed:

```
public ActionResult Create() {
        ViewBag.categoryId = new SelectList(db.Categories, "CategoryId", "Name");
        return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Question question) {
    try {
        var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            db.Questions.Add(question);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    } catch (DataException dex) {
        ModelState.AddModelError("",dex.Message);
    }
    ViewBag.categoryId = new SelectList(db.Categories, "CategoryId", "Name", question.Category.CategoryId);
    return View(question);
}
```

Does this run correctly?

If this doesn't work it must be a model-binding issue. The last thing I can think of trying is change the ViewBag calls to effect the field `Category` instead of `CategoryId`. Also update your view when making the DropDownList.

Comment: woohoo! that worked!
there was a catch though- only the question.Category.CategoryId was populated, question.CategoryId and question.Category.Name was null. I was able to get this information. But the ModelState still showed an error for question.Category.Name. Is there a way to reset the ModelState errors? Or should I not bother with, and directly execute the save?

Comment: What was the error? You can clear ModelState errors by calling something along the lines of... if (ModelState.ContainsKey("{key}"))
    ModelState["{key}"].Errors.Clear();

Comment: You would prevent the ModelState error on the Category.Name by not marking it as required

Comment: @ElliotSchmelliot the error i get is that Category.Name is null. I will try to clear the error, but how do i troubleshoot as to why category.name is not being populated?

Comment: @nakor yes, removing the required fixes it modelstate error, but then i need for the category controllers and models

Comment: @Madhu When you create a Question, you are not changing any Category fields, therefore I am guessing you have existing data in your database that is invalid. Run a query to see if you have any Category records with a null name, and if so, delete them.

Comment: you can have more than one Category model with different attributes. Then you don't have validation occuring in views where it's not needed.